# Pass data from dynamic page to persistent <Layout>{children}</Layout> component in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to use a persistent layout in Next.js and pass some data to it from my dynamic Blog post page.
[image]

So for example having this code (from next.js documentation):

```js
// pages/posts/[id].js

function Post({ post }) {
  return <p>{post.title}</p>;
}

// Trying to export the post title here
export const postTitle = ({ post }) => {
  return post.title;
};

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // Call an external API endpoint to get posts
  const res = await fetch("https://.../posts");
  const posts = await res.json();

  // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts
  const paths = posts.map((post) => ({
    params: { id: post.id },
  }));

  // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
  // { fallback: false } means other routes should 404.
  return { paths, fallback: false };
}

// This also gets called at build time
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  // params contains the post `id`.
  // If the route is like /posts/1, then params.id is 1
  const res = await fetch(`https://.../posts/${params.id}`);
  const post = await res.json();

  // Pass post data to the page via props
  return { props: { post } };
}

export default Post;
```

How can I grab that {post.title} and use it in my persistent layout component like so:

```js
// SiteLayout.js

import React from "react";
import { postTitle } from "../../pages/posts/[id]";

// Main Page  Wrapper
const SiteLayout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {postTitle && <p>{postTitle}</p>}
      <main className="layout">{children}</main>
    </>
  );
};

export default SiteLayout;
```

I've spent hours trying to make this work so I would really appreciate any pointers! Thank you!

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts has a pattern to be able to read the page's props in a layout component. Does that help?

Comment: @AKX with this will I be able to pass props to the layout via the getLayout function? (Edit ->) This seems the way to do it will try it out and post an update here. Thank you!