# Pass data from a page component to persistent layouts in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Suppose we have the following files in a Next.js project:

```js
// /components/SiteLayout.js
const SiteLayout = ({ children }) => <div>{/* ... */}</div>

export const getLayout = page => <SiteLayout>{page}</SiteLayout>

export default SiteLayout
```

```js
// /components/AccountSettingsLayout.js
import { getLayout as getSiteLayout } from './SiteLayout'

const AccountSettingsLayout = ({ children }) => <div>{/* ... */}</div>

export const getLayout = page =>
  getSiteLayout(<AccountSettingsLayout>{page}</AccountSettingsLayout>)

export default AccountSettingsLayout
```

```js
// /pages/account-settings/[id].js
import SiteLayout from '../../components/SiteLayout'
import { getLayout } from '../../components/AccountSettingsLayout'

const AccountSettingsBasicInformation = ({customProp}) => {
      const data = useFetchDataCustom()
      return <div> ... </div>
}

AccountSettingsBasicInformation.getLayout = getLayout

export default AccountSettingsBasicInformation
```

```js
//_app.js
class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props

    const getLayout =
      Component.getLayout || ((page) =>  page)

    return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)
  }
}

export default MyApp
```

Note in this `account-settings/[id].js` file, we use a custom hook to fetch data. That custom hook is dependent on the path variable `id` of the page. You can think of it as it will fetch data based on `id`.

Now, I'd like to pass data returned from `useFetchDataCustom` to both layouts `SiteLayout` and `AccountSettingsLayout`.

How can I do that? Appreciate any help!

(a side note: I'd like to keep `getLayout` function in my layout components)

Comment: Can you not move the data fetching hook to `_app`, and pass the data to the layouts there? You can easily convert `_app` to a function component so you can use the hook.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I am not sure I understand it well: The data fetching hook is in page file `/pages/account-settings/[id].js` not in `_app.js`. Could you expand a bit more on this approach? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, I realise that - my question was if you can't move the hook to `_app` instead. If you can't/don't want to do that, then you'd have to resort to React context (or any state library) to pass the data.

Comment: Got you. Yeah, we can't move the hook to `_app` since 1. I don't want to fetch data for each page 2. it's baesd on the path variable, so i suppose putting it into `_app.js` won't work. (I could be wrong for both points here) 
Yes, state library is one way to go. However, I wonder if you could check out the solution mentioned in the comment section of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68757561/pass-data-from-dynamic-page-to-persistent-layoutchildren-layout-component)

Comment: That is a similar question, not exactly the same. I couldn't figure out how "per-page layout" help pass data from page component to layout. Do you think that solution would help in my use case?

Comment: That approach uses Next.js' [data fetching methods](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) to retrieve the data on the server, while you're fetching the data client-side with a React hook. If you were to use those, it would be easier to pass the data to the layout as it would be fetched at the page level, rather than from a component like in your case.

Comment: Got you. It can only be fetched on the client side since I am using a graphql client for this.  
Given the above consideration, I think I will go for the state library approach. Thank you so much for your clear answer and explaination! Appreciate it.